# Sum of very large numbers

Tags: c

So I was wondering how to get sum of very large numbers (10 or more).
For example:

```
number1 = 10481481258125812;
number2 = 10041284812488248;
number3 = 10041248812482488;
```

I want to add these numbers and store into a variable called sum but I have never worked with such large numbers in C before.

Thank you!

Comment: What type are you using to represent these?

Comment: in this specific case a 64 bit integer will suffice.

Comment: Perhaps you want a [bignum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bignum) library like [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/)... Or just `long long` or `int64_t`

Answer (score 3):

### Working with a 64bit intiger

If you want to use numbers which are less than 64 bit, you can use int64_t / uint64_t / long long.
maximum sizes of these types:

- int64_t: 2^63 − 1 = 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
- uint64_t: 2^64 -1 = 18,446,744,073,709,551,615

int64_t and uint64_t are defined at [stdint.h](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/stdint.h)

### Working with gmplib

If you want to work with even larger number, you can use [GMPlib](https://gmplib.org/). A simple tutrial: https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~srirams/courses/csci2824-spr14/gmpTutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    long long number1 = 10481481258125812;
    long long number2 = 10041284812488248;
    long long number3 = 10041248812482488;
    long long sum = number1 + number2 + number3;
    printf("sum : %lld",sum);

}
```

Comment: `long` is not guaranteed to be 64 bits.

Comment: `long` is often the same length as an int.  When you have specific requirements as to the size of the data that must be represented, it is best to use the `stdint.h` library with types such as `int64_t` as it will portably ensure the requirements are met.

Comment: Thank you! I was using long long int but I used %d instead of %lld in printf so no wonder it was showing some random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Use `long long` which supports much larger numbers. In some compilers you can use `long long long` too, but you didn't mention the compiler you are using.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types for more information.

Comment: Can you cite a specific compiler that supports `long long long`?  Which platform does that run on?  The Wikipedia article doesn't mention the type.

Answer (score 0):

`unsigned long long` can handle such large numbers, up to at least 64 bits:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() {
    unsigned long long number1 = 10481481258125812;
    unsigned long long number2 = 10041284812488248;
    unsigned long long number3 = 10041248812482488;
    unsigned long long sum = number1 + number2 + number3;
    printf("sum: %llu\n", sum);
}
```

Comment: Suggest `"%llu"` for `unsigned long long`

Comment: Thank you! I was using long long int but I used %d instead of %lld in printf so no wonder it was showing some random numbers.

Comment: @Abhi_Meruga: You can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 0):

Type `long long` is specified as having at least 63 value bits and `unsigned long long` 64 value bits.

Some compilers (gcc and clang) support even larger integral types with 128 bits as `__int128` or `__int128_t` and `__uint128` or `__uint128_t`. These are non-standard types and the C library usually does not support them, so you would need to write conversion functions to and from strings yourself.

Beyond this, you would require an [Arbitrary Precision Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) package such as the [GNU multiple precision library](https://gmplib.org/).